# Zend Framework 2 installation on wamp server

Tags: wamp, zend-framework2

Can any one tell me how to install Zend framework 2 on Wamp server.

I found so many answer on Zend 1 but hardly any thing for Zend 2.

Regards
Bibhas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to install anything to use Zend Framework. ZF is an open source library of classes.

Simply create zend project and run it in WAMP.
Here are few resources:

1. [Zend QUickstart Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html)
2. [good zf tool tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/1348/using-zend_tool-to-start-up-your-zf-project/)

Or if you have custom setup:

1. download Zend Framework
2. in your project map include paths to the ZF
3. enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Best starting point is [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication)
Clone repo, call

> php composer.phar install

Or just follow documentation from SkeletonApp, it should be the fastest way how to have simple working application which you can modify / study.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to uncomment following line in php.ini in wamp server and restart, otherwise you will get error "Unable to find the socket  transport ssl"

extension=php_openssl.dll